# liquibase update data based on existing column

Tags: liquibase, liquibase-sql

Here, I am new to liquibase and I have a scenario where I need to add a new column to the existing table and have the value of this column based on existing column. However I was able to add column but I couldn't find a way to set default value for this column.

consider I have a table called table_1

| id | col1 | col2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 11 | 22 |
| 2 | 12 | 33 |
| 3 | 13 | 44 |

Now I want to add column col3 in the above table and have value of this column same as col2. I am expecting output something like

| id | col1 | col2 | col3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 11 | 22 | 22 |
| 2 | 12 | 33 | 33 |
| 3 | 13 | 44 | 44 |

Answer (score 1):

You've marked liquibase SQL, are you using SQL as the preferred language in your changelog?

I think if you are, a SQL statement might work:

```
-- liquibase formatted sql

-- changeset user1:1651490946175-1
UPDATE TABLENAME SET col3 = col2;
```

Otherwise, you could use similar syntax in json, yaml.